# What is shortcut key ? on Android Studio? android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" show android:text="hello_blank_fragment"

Tags: android

What is shortcut key ? on Android Studio?
 android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
 show 
 android:text="hello_blank_fragment"

Comment: What do you mean by "watching" a value?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Watch the value of string.xml?  That's not a code file, you can't debug it.  Its value only changes if you change it.  Watch it at a layout file?  Huh?

Comment: android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"   show android:text="hello_blank_fragment" what is shortcut key?

Answer (score 1):

You can findout your text in XML as follows :

```
android:text="@string/app_name"
```

You can get your value from Activity as follows :

```
getResourcse().getText(R.string.app_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is shortcut key ? on Android Studio? android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" show android:text="hello_blank_fragment"
the answer is ctrl+"-"